# Strange bug with Chrome/webkit. random size change

Tags: html, css, webkit

On this site. www.mylifepolicy.co.uk, if you click 'Get started Now' and click either of the options, the text below moves down a pixel or two.

This only happens on Chrome, and I'm not sure why.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

`.img-thumbnail` is being set as `display: inline-block;` but once it becomes `label.active img.img-thumbnail` it's switching to `display: block;`

If you make the default `block` so they stay the same once active, or both `inline-block` so they stay the same once active, it fixes your problem.

This **looks like** it has to do with the default `vertical-align` property for `inline-block` being `baseline` whereas `vertical-align` for `block` is `bottom` -- but I haven't done enough testing to be sure that that's the cause.

Comment: I tried changing them to both block and inline-block but it still does it. And sorry but I don't quite understand your last paragraph

Comment: Did you update the site? Because `label.active img.img-thumbnail {}` is still showing as `display: block;` and `.img-thumbnail {}` is still showing as `display: inline-block;`

Comment: I'm testing on local at the moment haha.